# How write a content from memory into array?

Tags: c, arrays, loops, microcontroller

I have an array down below

```
unsigned char pat6[8] = {0x3C,0xFF,0xC3,0xC3,0xC3,0xC3,0xFF,0x3C,};
```

How can I fill the array from the content of memory that I read from here ?

```
unsigned char read_byte()           //reading from EEPROM serially
{
    unsigned int i;
    sda=1;
    reead=0;
    for(i=0;i<8;i++)
    {
        reead=reead<<1;
        scl=1;
        _nop_();
        _nop_();
        if(sda==1)
            reead++;
        scl=0;
    }
    sda=0;
    return reead;               //Returns 8 bit data here
}
```

Thanks

```
void display_clear(unsigned char pattern[])//, int num)

 {
    unsigned int cnt, col, row; //, num ;


     row = 1;
          //for (cnt = num*8 ; cnt < (num*8+8) ; cnt ++ )   //display pattern each character
          for (cnt = 0 ; cnt < 8 ; cnt ++ ) //display pattern each character
            {
              P3 = ~pattern[cnt];
              P1 = ~row;

              delay_ms(100) ; // delay of 1 ms
              row = row<<1;


            }

       row = 0x00;

 }
```

Friends, the function above, I used for displaying the array.....
And I want to fill the data in array from serial memory

I tried to do like this :

```
//begin of read 2048 byte from serial memory AT24C16

     for (i=0;i<2048;i++)
      {
          j[i]=read_byte();
          aknowledge();
      }

   //end of read 2048 byte from serial memory AT24C16
```

and got error :

**24C16_RW.C(229): error C216: subscript on non-array or too many dimensions**

Are there any other ways ?

THanks

Comment: What is `scl`? where is it declared?

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if I understood your question correctly, but I think that with a for statement will work.

```
for (i=0, i<8,i++)
pat6[i]=read_byte();
```

what i dont get is how the read function will know how to read sequentially. i think that with that implementation the whole array will be filled with the same byte.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the below pseudo-code.

```
function write_into_array()
{
    for i=0 to 8 {
        array[i] = value-to-be-stored;
    }
}
```

But in your code, where is `scl` variable declared? or is it a global variable just like the `pat6[]` array?

OTOH, you should get rid of the extra `,` at the end.

```
unsigned char pat6[8] = {0x3C,0xFF,0xC3,0xC3,0xC3,0xC3,0xFF,0x3C,};
```